# How to get the difference in miliseconds between two Timestamps which are of different timezone in Javascript

Tags: javascript

i wanted to get the difference of two timestamps of different timezone in javascript:

```
var firstTime ="2017-07-21 04:34:21"; 
var timeZone1:"+0100"; 
var secondTime ="2017-07-21 04:36:27";     
var timeZone2:"+0124";
```

How we can get the difference in miliseconds ?

Comment: 0124 is a timezone?

Comment: Create date objects and then use `Date.getTime()` to get value in milliseconds and perform your arithmetic operations. You can also refer following link to check how to create date with timezone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s

Comment: @JaromandaX +0124 is Warsaw Mean Time --> short interesting read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B01:24

Answer (score 1):

Convert your strings into [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. These generally work well in JavaScript `Date` constructors. Then simply subtract one from the other

```js
var firstTime ="2017-07-21T04:34:21"; 
var timeZone1 = "+01:00"; 
var secondTime = "2017-07-21T04:36:27";     
var timeZone2 = "+01:24";  

const firstDate  = new Date(firstTime + timeZone1)
const secondDate = new Date(secondTime + timeZone2)
console.log('firstDate', firstDate)
console.log('secondDate', secondDate)
console.info('diff', firstDate - secondDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment.js (https://momentjs.com/) for get the current timestamp from different time zone.

But don´t forget : "Time Zone != Offset"
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info

Another good example:
[Get timezone difference in hours with moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684748/get-timezone-difference-in-hours-with-moment)